# Tensorflow 2.0: Loading Data from CSV files

Tags: python, matlab, csv, tensorflow

New to ML & Tensorflow, and this is a school project using Tensorflow 2.0. I'm trying to create a Neural Network model that predicts the electric field of a simple antenna given the frequency. I used MATLAB to model ~500 antennas at varying frequencies to test. Matlab output the values of each point in xyz coordinates which I converted to a CSV file. Each CSV file is essentially a matrix, and I transposed the matrix for 3 columns and 440 rows. These files will act as my training set for the model.

However, the CSV files aren't labeled with x, y, and z for each column. Is there a way to load in these 500 files to create a matrix for each CSV file? Is there a way to do it without having the columns labeled x, y, and z?

Also, I'd like to specify the frequency of each matrix (each csv file). Would it be best to create 500 separate files that specify the frequency value, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think Pandas could solve your problem. Read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-read-csv-file-using-pandas-ab1f5e7e7b58) blog.

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply. I've been looking at examples that also use Pandas but haven't quite found what I was thinking of. I had a possible breakthrough though. Tomorrow I'll try processing the data myself and creating four separate CSV files for x, y, z, and frequency variables, with each row among the four files representing a single antenna model. I believe my current files are too messy to load data from and I'll need to put it in a specific form. I'll update my post with results for anyone in the future to use.

Comment: Since your using tensorflow, there's an inbuilt function to load your dataset from a csv https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#tfdataexperimentalcsvdataset